# How do signals work when queue_free is called?

Tags: godot, memory, gdscript, messaging

Consider this setup:

```
* KinematicBody2D (Player)
|- Sprite (icon.png)
|- VisibilityNotifier2D
```

With `Player.gd`:

```
class_name Player extends KinematicBody2D
signal unvisible

onready var visibility_notifier :VisibilityNotifier2D = $VisibilityNotifier2D

func _ready() -> void:
    visibility_notifier.connect("screen_exited", self, "__on_screen_exited")

func __on_screen_exited() -> void:
    emit_signal("unvisible")
```

Now I have a template `Level.gd`:

```
* Node2D (Level)
|- Player
```

```
extends Node2D

onready var player :Player = $Player

export var debug_no_enemy  = false
export var debug_no_player = true

func _ready() -> void:
    player.connect("unvisible", self, "_reset_level")
    if debug_no_player:
        player.queue_free()

func _reset_level() -> void:
    print("reset")
    get_tree().reload_current_scene()
```

The `print` statement proves that this setup make a kind of infinite loop of reset because the signal `screen_exited` is still emited when the player is `queue_free`.

Is it expected?

---

I am even more surprised with this modified version which produces the same thing:

```
func _ready() -> void:
    if debug_no_player:
        player.queue_free()
    player.connect("unvisible", self, "_reset_level")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is to not emit the signal if the node is queued for deletion:

```
func __on_screen_exited() -> void:
    if !is_queued_for_deletion():
        emit_signal("unvisible")
```

Note that this is happening before the node is freed. Using `queue_free` ensure all the steps needed to remove the `Node` safely happen between frames.

After the `Node` is removed from the Scene, Godot will disconnect signals from it, and then disconnect signals to it, then finally release the Node.

At the point you get this notification, the `Node` has disappeared because it is removed from the scene, but it has not been disconnected yet.

---

You are, of course, reloading the scene, which causes the loop:

```
func _reset_level() -> void:
    print("reset")
    get_tree().reload_current_scene()
```

Presumably, if you are running on a debug mode where there is no player, then the removal of the player should not cause the scene to reload. Thus:

```
func _ready() -> void:
    if debug_no_player:
        player.queue_free()
    else:
        player.connect("unvisible", self, "_reset_level")
```

Although, I'd argue for making the player its own scene and instance it (and connect its signals) only if `debug_no_player` is `false`, instead of removing the player if `debug_no_player` is true.