# How to disconnect all signals of an emitter?

Tags: godot, gdscript, messaging

This a follow-up question of this [one](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/192244/150409)

I want to disconnect multiple signals before using `queue_free()`.

In docs we have:

```
void disconnect ( String signal, Object target, String method )
```

Is it possible to disconnect all signals of an emitter without using the names of the signals or methods involved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the list of signals with [`get_signal_list`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-get-signal-list):

```
var signals = node.get_signal_list();
for cur_signal in signals:
    print(cur_signal.name);
```

Then you can get the list of connections for each one with [`get_signal_connection_list`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-get-signal-connection-list) to find where those signals are connected to:

```
var signals = node.get_signal_list();
for cur_signal in signals:
    var conns = node.get_signal_connection_list(cur_signal.name);
    for cur_conn in conns:
        print(cur_conn.signal);
        print(cur_conn.target);
        print(cur_conn.method);
```

That is the information of signal connections that connect *from* an object. Which you need to disconnect them:

```
node.disconnect(cur_conn.signal, cur_conn.target, cur_conn.method)
```

---

On the other hand, if you want the information of signal connections that connect *to* an object, you can use [`get_incoming_connections`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-get-incoming-connections) instead:

```
var conns = node.get_incoming_connections();
for cur_conn in conns:
    print(cur_conn.signal_name);
    print(cur_conn.source);
    print(cur_conn.method_name);
```

Disconnecting them would be:

```
cur_conn.source.disconnect(cur_conn.signal_name, node, cur_conn.method_name)
```